Spring Azure BlobStorage: Can't access subfolders after Springboot 3 migration
I have a strange problem. After upgrading to Springboot 3.3.1 from Springboot 2 i can't access files in subfolders in my blob container anymore. blobClient.exists() returns false for all files in a subfolder. If a file is directly in the root of the container, all works fine.
The uploading of the files is done in another service and wasn't changed or altered.
For Springboot 3 I am using the spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage-blob from spring-cloud-azure-dependencies in version 5.14.0 (newest available stable)
https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/storagecontainer/folder/file  -> does not work 
https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/storagecontainer/file -> works fine 
How can I access the subfolders of a container? Did Microsoft change the way how to access them in the SP3-Versions of their libs?
Update: It seems to work with Spring 3.2.7 and Azure 5.12. Without any actual code changes

fyi unless you're using ADLS (hierarchical directories), Azure Storage doesn't have subfolders - the / is just part of the name (beyond the container, which is a thing)

Please don't add solutions/answers to questions. Since you resolved this with a version change, this question should be closed (or post your edit as a proper answer, not as an edit to the question)

Nope, its not solved, since it doesn't work with Springboot 3.3 as I want it to work.
